# Problem with Deploying Next.js to Azure App Service using Github Actions

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I have problem with deploying next.js to azure app service using github actions currently.
Although I am trying to deploy, I am continuously getting an error that says 'No such file or directory'

[image]

The yaml file is the same as the below.

```
Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - clsreact3

on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - master 
  
env:
  AZURE_WEPAPP_NAME: clsreact3
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'
  NODE_VERSION: '14.x'

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    name: Build and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@main
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}
    - name: npm install, build, and test
      run: |
        # Build and test the project, then
        # deploy to Azure Web App.
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
      working-directory: my-app-path
    - name: 'Deploy to Azure WebApp'
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with: 
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

If more info is needed, please refer here.
https://github.com/scl2589/next.js-tutorial

Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure of the error, but your project doesn't appears right. In package.json you have start script (and dev one too): `node server.js` while your project has no `server.js` file. Also, avoid mixing package managers. I can see both `yarn.lock` and `package-lock.json`. Are you sure the project even works on your system? Also, don't checkout `node_modules`. Add it to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

So you have wrong `working-directory: my-app-path` and to make sure that you use correct working directory please add this step before:

```yaml
 - name: List directory
      run: |
         ls .
```

I can't provide a better answer as I don't know your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

I am using their local git deployment method. By creating a remote (named `azure`) referring to the git of the azure app service (you can get it in deployment section).

I complete my tasks on my repository (on master branch) then I just do this to deploy

```
git pull origin master
git push azure master
```